# text to xml via python issue

Tags: python-3.x, scripting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZGDU.png)`My code converts text to xml via python, but there is a bug in my program. Not able to debug it.
It only reads the 1st row, but as soon as the counter reaches 2nd line, the error indexerror:out of range occurs. Please help. If you see the file, each entry has 14 rows to be precise and these 14 entries are seperated by a pipe ( | ) delimiter. The code works fine if I keep adding entries in first row, but the moment i use 2nd row, it errors out.

The O/P of the program when all alphabets are in 1st row is attached in the image.
import sys[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7j30.png)
The moment i shift any letter in 2nd role, my code is giving out of range error.
No matter I enter row[0], row[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZGDU.png), row[2] etc or insert row[i] and increment i each time, the stacktrace is the same

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Python\Projects\xmlfile.py", line 17, in 
clnt.text = row[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZGDU.png)
IndexError: list index out of range

The contents of the text file are (text.txt):
A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|
O

```
import csv
from lxml import etree as et

csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)
root = et.Element("Processes")

i = 0

data = []
with open("test.txt") as file:
for row in csv.reader(file, delimiter="|"):
name = et.SubElement(root, "name")
time = et.SubElement(name, "Time")
time.text = row[i]
i += 1
clnt = et.SubElement(name, "Client")
clnt.text = row[i]
i += 1
usr = et.SubElement(name, "User")
usr.text = row[i]
i += 1
txtstat = et.SubElement(name, "textstatus")
txtstat.text = row[i]
i += 1
num = et.SubElement(name, "number")
num.text = row[i]
i += 1
pid = et.SubElement(name, "processid")
pid.text = row[i]
i += 1
prog = et.SubElement(name, "program")
prog.text = row[i]
i += 1
randnum = et.SubElement(name, "randomnumber")
randnum.text = row[i]
i += 1
pidandwp = et.SubElement(name, "processidandwp")
pidandwp.text = row[i]
i += 1
userclnt = et.SubElement(name, "userclient")
userclnt.text = row[i]
i += 1
tid = et.SubElement(name, "transactionid")
tid.text = row[i]
i += 1
add1 = et.SubElement(name, "additional1")
add1.text = row[i]
i += 1
add2 = et.SubElement(name, "additional2")
add2.text = row[i]
i += 1
add3 = et.SubElement(name, "additional3")
add3.text = row[i]
i += 1
add3 = et.SubElement(name, "additional3")
add3.text = row[i]
i += 1
add3 = et.SubElement(name, "additional3")
add3.text = row[i]
i += 1
add3 = et.SubElement(name, "additional3")
add3.text = row[i]
data.append(row)
xml_datas = et.tostring(root, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding="utf-8")
print(xml_datas.decode())`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work better, It reads from the file and doesn't use `i` in the way you were using it and can dynamically work with rows of any length.

```py
import csv
from lxml import etree as et

csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)
root = et.Element("Processes")

row_names = [
  'Time',
  'Client',
  'User',
  'number',
  'processid',
  'program',
  'randomnumber',
  'processidandwp',
  'userclient',
  'transactionid',
  'additional1',
  'additional2',
  'additional3'
]

with open("test.txt") as file:
  for row in csv.reader(file, delimiter="|"):
    name = et.SubElement(root, "name")
    for i in range(len(row)):
      node = et.SubElement(name, row_names[i])
      node.text = row[i]

xml_datas = et.tostring(root, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding="utf-8")
print(xml_datas.decode())`
```

Comment: Even after trying this, i get the same output. i tried it as well

Comment: what error are you getting? Can you add the stacktrace to your question?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python\Projects\xmlfile.py", line 17, in <module>
    clnt.text = row[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
PS C:\Python\Projects>

Comment: If you having trailing newlines in your file it might cause issues, I would suggest using `strip` on the contents of the file before passing it to the csv reader, or cleaning up the file yourself

Comment: can you send me a sample code to understand better.

Comment: if you're going to have multiple lines in your file you need to ensure that each line has has the same number of entries or you'll run into issues like this

Comment: Can you post the test file you're using that has multiple lines in your question?

Comment: is there a better way to code it as the number of entries in each line is different, but overall the columns are fixed that is 14.

Comment: I have added the txt file

Comment: try this on for size

Comment: Getting this now

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python\Projects\convertxml.py", line 27, in <module>
    node = et.SubElement(name, row_names[i])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: You have to many entries in your row, add more names to `row_names`

Comment: you said you have a maximum of 14 columns?

Comment: if so, ensure you have 14 column names in `row_names`

Comment: It amost works. Just 1 issue here. It creates seperate xml tags for entries that i put in 2nd or 3rd row. The code should know that the 14 columns belongs to one <name> tag and then it should proceeed with the next one. Hope you can understand. For ex...if I add M and N in 2nd row, it should add it in the first tag, rather it starts a new name tag and assigns like this
  <name>
    <Time>M</Time>
    <Client>N</Client>
  </name>

Comment: That's as simple as refactoring the example above, otherwise, I think that sounds like another post

Comment: Sure i will create another post. Hope you can help me there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75298495/incorrect-tag-assigment-in-xml-via-python
I created a new post. Can you please help