# incorrect tag assigment in xml via python

Tags: python, xml, csv

I have a script which almost works to conver text to xml in python. But I have just one issue and need help.
Each line item has 14 entries ( the 12th, 13th and 14th entries are in the 2nd row ). So the entries in my text file looks like:

5372|,EMF|2023011309094800|000|ABCSYS||RANDOMTXT||1|25727,00078,B4||43AE5E5C169904E0E0063BBEAE2CDF2F|42010A2A25FA1EDBB2D97D4DE84DB471|
5373|,EME|2023011309094800|000|ABCSYS||RANDOMTXT||1|25727,00078,B4|USER001|43AE5E5C169904E0E0063BBEAE2CDF2F|42010A2A25FA1EDBB2D97D4DE84DB471|
5374|,EME|2023011309094800|000|ABCSYS||RANDOMTXT||1|25727,00078,B4|Job:ABC_WORKFLOW_SYSTEM09084801|43AE5E5C169904E0E0063BBEAE2CDF2F|42010A2A25FA1EDBB2D97D4DE84DB471|
5375|p,E0A|2023011309094800|000|ABCSYS||RANDOMTXT||1|25727,00078,B4|&aUSER&b001|43AE5E5C169904E0E0063BBEAE2CDF2F|42010A2A25FA1EDBB2D97D4DE84DB471|
5376|n,D01|2023011309094800|000|ABCSYS||RANDOMTXT||1|25727,00078,B4|00560|43AE5E5C169904E0E0063BBEAE2CDF2F|42010A2A25FA1EDBB2D97D4DE84DB471|
5363|x,A14|2023013117274500|500|SXG6JYN|TXN|YDMMR_TRNS_COMSALES_TO_FNR_DTH|C7000EBA|5|13538,00057,D3|YDMMR_TRNS_COMSALES_TO_FNR_F010243GET_DATA|43AE5E5C16990390E0063D769C6864E8|42
010A2A25FA1EEDA8B68FD75FA13EBE|
5364|l,A19|2023013117274500|500|SXG6JYN|TXN|YDMMR_TRNS_COMSALES_TO_FNR_DTH|C7000EBA|5|13538,00057,D3|GT_MATDOC[1]-BKTXT->APIabtpdasy6185|43AE5E5C16990390E0063D769C6864E8|42010A2A2
5FA1EEDA8B68FD75FA13EBE|

Expected out in xml will be like

The issue with the below code is, the moment the entries are in the 2nd row, it creates a parent tag. I want all 14 elements do come under 1 parent tag and then create a new parent tag for the subsequent set of 14 elements. I have attached a screenshot of how i get the o/p now which is incorrect.

```
import csv
from lxml import etree as et

csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)
root = et.Element("Processes")

row_names = [
  'Time',
  'Client',
  'User',
  'number',
  'processid',
  'program',
  'randomnumber',
  'processidandwp',
  'userclient',
  'transactionid',
  'additional1',
  'additional2',
  'additional3',
  'additional4'
  ]

with open("test.txt") as file:
    for row in csv.reader(file, delimiter="|"):
      name = et.SubElement(root, "name")
      for i in range(len(row)):
        node = et.SubElement(name, row_names[i])
        node.text = row[i]

xml_datas = et.tostring(root, pretty_print=True, 
xml_declaration=True, encoding="utf-8")
print(xml_datas.decode())


Current output
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sNmH.png

</Processes>
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
  <name>
    <Time>6354</Time>
    <Client>,EGZ</Client>
    <User>2023012711283700</User>
    <number>900</number>
    <processid>DDIC</processid>
    <program>S000</program>
    <randomnumber>R_JR_BTCJOBS_GENERATOR</randomnumber>
    <processidandwp></processidandwp>
    <userclient>1</userclient>
    <transactionid>25737,00088,B5</transactionid>
    <additional1>text</additional1>
    <additional2>43AE5E5C16990580E0063BBEAE21BEA8</additional2>
    <additional3>42010A2A25FA1EDDA7CN</additional3>
    <additional4>BDA81EE66224C</additional4>
    <additional5>000000000000000000/00000000000</additional5>
   </name>
   <name>
     <Time>6355</Time>
     <Client>,EGZ</Client>
     <User>2023012711283700</User>
     <number>900</number>
     <processid>DDIC</processid>
     <program>S000</program>
     <randomnumber>R_JR_BTCJOBS_GENERATOR</randomnumber>
     <processidandwp></processidandwp>
     <userclient>1</userclient>
     <transactionid>25737,00088,B5</transactionid>
     <additional2>43AE5E5C16990580E0063BBEAE21BEA8</additional2>
     <additional3>42010A2A25FA1EDDA7CN</additional3>
     <additional4>BDA81EE66224C</additional4>
     <additional5>000000000000000000/00000000000</additional5>
    </name>
 </Processes>
```

Comment: Your original post did not have correct indentation. I made assumptions. Please fix accordingly which may be a key reason for your issue. Also, please post a sample of CSV (copy from text editor) for [mre].

Comment: I didnt get you. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: Also the indentation in my code is correct. Its just that its not corextly copied here. Sorry about that

Comment: Can you please share your input (as text - not image) and the requested output (as text)

Comment: Is `|L|M|N` is a new line in the csv?

Comment: L M n is a new line in text file, but the code should know that the first 14 columns belongs to one set...it shouldnt create another parent <name> tag

Comment: Also I don't see a way to add text file as an attachment here to my question. Any idea?

Comment: Update the post with the required XML output (as text)

Comment: I have added the required output as text now. Please check

Comment: It works almost..but the output is not structured..I am getting everything in unstructured format like this

Comment: <Processes><name><Time>A</Time><Client>B</Client><User>C</User><number>D</number><processid>E</processid><program>F</program><randomnumber>G</randomnumber><processidandwp>H</processidandwp><userclient>I</userclient><transactionid>J</transactionid><additional1>K</additional1><additional2>L</additional2><additional3>M</additional3><additional4>N</additional4></name></Processes>

Comment: Also, will it work if I have many rows in my text file, because this is just a sample, my actual text file has many rows and not just 2 rows.

Comment: Ok, I figured out how to get the structure correctly, but I see 1 limitation here...if I have more than 2 rows...it doesnt capture them in a new parent <name > node.

Answer (score 0):

The below should work

```
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

row_names = [
    'Time',
    'Client',
    'User',
    'number',
    'processid',
    'program',
    'randomnumber',
    'processidandwp',
    'userclient',
    'transactionid',
    'additional1',
    'additional2',
    'additional3',
    'additional4'
]
root = ET.Element("Processes")
counter = 0
with open("data.csv", 'r') as file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter="|")
    sub_root = ET.SubElement(root, 'name')
    for row in csv_reader:
        for name in row:
            if counter < len(row_names) and name:
                ele = ET.SubElement(sub_root, row_names[counter])
                ele.text = name
                counter += 1

ET.dump(root)
```

output

```
<Processes>
    <name>
        <Time>A</Time>
        <Client>B</Client>
        <User>C</User>
        <number>D</number>
        <processid>E</processid>
        <program>F</program>
        <randomnumber>G</randomnumber>
        <processidandwp>H</processidandwp>
        <userclient>I</userclient>
        <transactionid>J</transactionid>
        <additional1>K</additional1>
        <additional2>L</additional2>
        <additional3>M</additional3>
        <additional4>N</additional4>
    </name>
</Processes>
```

Comment: Ok, I figured out how to get the structure correctly, but I see 1 limitation here...if I have more than 2 rows...it doesnt capture them in a new parent <name > node.

Comment: You need to explain the logic and the possible input. Once you will do that the code will be adopted

Comment: so here is the thing that i actually need.  The code should insert all the subelements under one parent <name> tag irrespective of whether they are in one single row or 2 rows.
For the subsequent rows (3,4) (5,6) etc , it should do the same. It should be dynamic since the number of rows will keep increasing on a daily basis.

Comment: Publish a real csv and xml that should be the output. (add them to the post as text)

Comment: Its a very long text file, but the entries in the text file are something like this..
5373|,EME|2023011309094800|000|ABCSYS||RANDOMTXT||1|25727,00078,B4|USER001|43AE5E5C169904E0E0063BBEAE2CDF2F|42010A2A25FA1EDBB2D97D4DE84DB471|
5364|l,A19|2023013117274500|500|SXG6JYN|SE38|YDMMR_TRNS_COMSALES_TO_FNR_DTH|C7000EBA|5|13538,00057,D3|GT_MATDOC[1]-BKTXT->APIabtpdasy6185|43AE5E5C16990390E0063D769C6864E8|42010A2A2
5FA1EEDA8B68FD75FA13EBE|

Comment: so each event has some texts as you can see which starts with a number 5373, 5364 etc and each value is delimited by ( | )

Comment: so the values of one event should go under one name tag.

Comment: the other rows in the real text file has same entries of the same structure but for different events. I am not attaching it as its very very huge. So if you can help in creating a dynamic code with the sample i gave it iwll be great.

Comment: Add it to the post and the output xml

Comment: I have added it, please note that its just a sample and I need a dynamic code to incorprate n number of records like this if you can please.

Comment: How can we tell how many lines in csv should create 1 name element? You did not added output xml

Comment: Every 2 lines shluld create 1 name element. I added the expected output im the post itself as a sample...

Comment: Can someone help?